# Connect openshift pod to external mysql database

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, openshift

I am trying to set up a generic pod on OpenShift 4 that can connect to a mysql server running on a separate VM outside the OpenShift cluster (testing using local openshift crc). However when creating the deployment, I'm unable to connect to the mysql server from inside the pod (for testing purposes).

The following is the deployment that I use:

```
kind: "Service"
apiVersion: "v1"
metadata:
  name: "mysql"
spec:
  ports:
    - name: "mysql"
      protocol: "TCP"
      port: 3306
      targetPort: 3306 
      nodePort: 0
selector: {}
---
kind: "Endpoints"
apiVersion: "v1"
metadata:
  name: "mysql" 
subsets: 
  - addresses:
      - ip: "***ip of host with mysql database on it***" 
    ports:
      - port: 3306 
        name: "mysql"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: DeploymentConfig
metadata:
  name: "deployment"
spec: 
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: "mysql"
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: "test-mysql"
          image: "***image repo with docker image that has mysql package installed***"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3306
              protocol: "TCP"
          env:
            - name: "MYSQL_USER"
              value: "user" 
            - name: "MYSQL_PASSWORD"
              value: "******" 
            - name: "MYSQL_DATABASE"
              value: "mysql_db"  
            - name: "MYSQL_HOST"
              value: "***ip of host with mysql database on it***" 
            - name: "MYSQL_PORT"
              value: "3306"
```

I'm just using a generic image for testing purposes that has standard packages installed (net-tools, openjdk, etc.)

I'm testing by going into the deployed pod via the command:

```
$ oc rsh {{ deployed pod name }}
```

however when I try to run the following command, I cannot connect to the server running mysql-server

```
$ mysql --host **hostname** --port 3306 -u user -p
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '**hostname**:3306' (111)
```

I've also tried to create a route from the service and point to that as a "fqdn" alternative but still no luck.

If I try to ping the host (when inside the pod), I cannot reach it either. But I can reach the host from outside the pod, and from inside the pod, I can ping sites like google.com or github.com

For reference, the image being used is essentially the following dockerfile

```
FROM ubi:8.0

RUN dnf install -y python3 \
                   wget \
                   java-1.8.0-openjdk \ 
                   https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm \
                   postgresql-devel

WORKDIR /tmp


RUN wget http://repo.mysql.com/mysql-community-release-el7-5.noarch.rpm && \
    rpm -ivh mysql-community-release-el7-5.noarch.rpm && \
    dnf update -y && \
    dnf install mysql -y && \
    wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-J/mysql-connector-java-5.1.48.tar.gz && \
    tar zxvf mysql-connector-java-5.1.48.tar.gz && \
    mkdir -p /usr/share/java/ && \
    cp mysql-connector-java-5.1.48/mysql-connector-java-5.1.48-bin.jar /usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar

RUN dnf install -y tcping \
                   iputils \
                   net-tools
```

I imagine there is something I am fundamentally misunderstanding about connecting to an external database from inside OpenShift, and/or my deployment configs need some adjustment somewhere. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Trust you are using “mysql” service name in place of host name in the db connect statement

Comment: @NatarajMedayhal yes its just the IP of the VM running a mysql server instance. I've tested connecting to this VM from my local computer with the same connection string and that works fine, is this what you mean my using the "mysql" service name?

Comment: i mean k8s service name which is getting created

Comment: @NatarajMedayhal yes the k8s service name is "mysql" - okay so I guess are you saying that for the connection string, I should be referring to "mysql" i.e. mysql --host mysql --port 3306 -u user -p ?
EDIT: I assume that isn't what you mean now, the connection string has been tested pointing to the VM IP directly, the service ClusterIP, and the route FQDN without any of it working

Comment: yes that's correct in the connect string use service name.

Comment: @NatarajMedayhal I've tried your suggestion but it still throws an error:

sh-4.4$ mysql --host mysql --port 3306 -u user -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql:3306' (111)

Comment: there is nothing seems to wrong at k8s side as configuration from k8s are proper.  As mentioned by you ping to hostname is not happening directly from the pod this can be checked from firewall rules side, any blocking rule for external connection from the cluster not to happen and db configuration are proper and its not blocking anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the conversation for the post, it looks to be a firewall issue. I've tested again with the same config, but instead of an external mysql db, I've tested via deploying mysql in openshift as well and the pods can connect. Since I don't have control of the firewall in the organisation, and the config didn't change between the two deployments, I'll mark this as solved as there isn't much more I can do to test it